# is it possible to expire in 1 min in model of particular data like stored otp in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, google-api-nodejs-client

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const expirationTime=10
let currentTime = Date.now();

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    fullName: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    mobile_number: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    otp_instance: [{
            otp_id: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required: false
            },
            otp: {
                type: String,
        // index: {expires:'1m'},
                required: false
            },
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date()
      },
      expiration_time: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date(currentTime+(expirationTime * 1000))
      },
      // otp: { type: String, index: { expires: 300 }}
        }],
    resetLink: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    isAccountVerified: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    activeStatus: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "0",
    },
    deletedStatus: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "0",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
  );

// userSchema.createIndex( { otp: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 36000 } )
const userModel = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
module.exports = userModel;
```

> is it possible to expire in 1 min in model of particular data like stored otp in mongodb
> is it possible to expire in 1 min in model of particular data like stored otp in mongodb
> is it possible to expire in 1 min in model of particular data like stored otp in mongodb> is it possible to expire in 1 min in model of particular data like stored otp in mongodb> is it possible to expire in 1 min in model of particular data like stored otp in mongodb> is it possible to expire in 1 min in model of particular data like stored otp in mongodb> is it possible to expire in 1 min in model of particular data like stored otp in mongodb

Comment: You can delete the whole document, but not a particular field from it.